# SOAP::WSDL with xml data object

Tags: xml, perl, web-services, soap, wsdl

I wrote the following program to send a SOAP request.

```
use SOAP::Lite +trace;
use XML::LibXML;

$client = SOAP::Lite->service('https://services.company.domain/svcfile.svc?wsdl');
$xmlFileHandle = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'request.xml');   
$xmlContent = SOAP::Data->type('xml' => $xmlFileHandle);   
$result = $client->RetrieveInfo($xmlContent);
print "$result";
```

When I go through the XML that is returned it says bad request ( Error 400).
When I paste the raw XML code in SOAPUI it works properly and returns the information needed.

The line that's causing the bad request error is :

```
$result = $client->RetrieveInfo($xmlContent);
```

How to correct this error?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at the actual request and its headers?

Comment: @simbabque I'm not sure if you were referring to http headers or soap header.But the request does not have a soap header but has a soap body.

Comment: I meant the Http headers. Or rather the whole thing. The trace mode should help. If not, install LWL::ConsoleLogger::Everywhere and use that. It will give you the full request. Since you say the xml works from another program it must be the http headers.

Comment: @simbabque
The WSDL file expects a literal variable as input.But the variable `result` is of type `SOAP::Data=HASH(0x33f11a0)`.So I need to pass an xml literal.How can I do this?